# Find the $α$ values by which the integral below is convergent

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Find the $α$ values $(α ∈ R)$ by which the integral below is convergent.

$\int^{+∞}_{-∞} |x|^{-α}arctan(\frac{x}{x^4+1})dx$

Since we know that the integral of an odd function from $-a$ to $a$ is always equal to zero, I thought that this specific integral converges for every $α$. Is this correct?
I even tried to approximate this function to $\frac{1}{|x|^α}$, since we know that $-1≤arctan≤1$, so it results that the integral converges for $α>1$. Is it that easy, or am I missing something?

Comment: The answer depends on whether the intergral is an improper Riemann integral or a Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Note that your conclusion is invalid for at least the case when $\alpha>0.$

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a Riemann integral!

Comment: In fact, this may not exist except for the case when $\alpha$ vanishes, for even in the case when $\alpha<0,$ it still is not true that the integral of an odd function over $(-\infty,+\infty)$ is always zero, since we evaluate this by splitting the domain into $(-\infty,a]$ and $[a,+\infty),$ which is not necessarily always zero.